# Hibernate: concurrent insert

Tags: spring, hibernate, concurrency, hikaricp

I have a multithread handler, which is taking entries from Kafka topic and saving data to PostgreSQL.

Entries in Kafka can represent:

- create new entity
- update existing entity

Since the handler is multithread, update entry can come prior to create entry. For that reason I check on update if entity persists in DB and make insert on negative case (and vice-versa: make update instead of insert if entity has already persisted)

I face a UK_CONSTAINT_VIOLATION here because changes made by different threads seem to be cached and at the moment of commit, contains few insert statements with the same UK.

I've tried with no success:

1. Mark handler with `@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED)`
2. Configure Hikari with:

```
hikari:
  auto-commit: false
  maximum-pool-size: 5
  transaction-isolation: TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED
```

3. Use caching on Entity level:

```
@Cacheable
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
```

[image: diagram]

Comment: That generally shouldn't be an issue with a sequence at all. A sequence is incremented as soon as the next value is requested, within or without a transaction. So you must be doing something else that is strange.

Comment: Hi, tanks for your comment. Indeed, I did interprete the root case wrong. I'll update my question now

Comment: If it already exists (and you get the error) just ignore the error. This happens because the UPDATE probably triggers first and then the CREATE. You could locking on the database but that would be a performance bottleneck. I would say if the CREATE fails ignore it. If the UPDATE fails (meaning a CREATE came through), catch the error and make it an UPDATE instead of CREATE. Or depending on your database use an UPSERT instead (but you would have to ditch JPA for that).

Comment: I can't ignore if it is already exists - number of updates can be more that 1. Why can't I enable dirty read uncommited changes?

Comment: The fact that hibernate generated an error doesn't mean it already has seen it or that changes are already flushed to the database. So trying to fix it at that level won't help. Also why couldn't you ignore the create if it already exists? For the UPDATE change the CREATE to an UPDATE... I don't see the issue with that.

Comment: Hi, thanx for the suggestion. I switched to UPSERT instead